# Make a Single-movies.php file for Custom Post "movies"

Tags: wordpress

anyone who can help me to make this code exactly which I want

```
<div id="container">


<div class="clearfix"></div>

<?php   $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'movies',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'order' => DESC );   $myquery = new WP_Query($args);
    if($myquery->have_posts()) : 
        while($myquery->have_posts()) :
           $myquery->the_post(); ?>


            <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>


                <h1><a title="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>


                <div class="entry-content">

                    <?php the_content(); ?>


                </div>          </div>


<?php    endwhile; endif; ?>

</div>


<?php include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/sidebar_single.php'); ?>
```

In this code I'm getting all the posts when I'm click on any post, on single-movies.php its showing all 10 posts. But I need only one movie post which i click. and if you think its wrong just give me advice because I have no idea about this.

thanx in advance Kumar

Answer (score 0):

how about

in your functions.php paste this ( unless you already have it setup!! )

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'Movies',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'movie' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'movie' )
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        )
    );
}
```

then in your template file paste this where you want your post to be shown

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'movies', 'posts_per_page' => 1 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
?>
  <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <h1>
      <a title="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark">
        <?php the_title(); ?>
      </a>
    </h1>
    <div class="entry-content">
       <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
   </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

hopefully this might help.
more info [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types)

Marty

Comment: Superb Thanx, Dude..Its a rock time. Great work Bro! Stackoverflow Please promote this buddy
;-)

Comment: Hello Marty, Sorry But I'm back, I got the problem, Its working and showing me only one post, but its a big issue that, When I'm click on any movie, its showing me only one movie post, (i.e I'm click on avatar movie its showing me avartar movie post, but when I'm click on stargate movie its showing me avatar movie post. Please help its a big issue)